# I need to concatenate two elements of an unsigned char array into and keep it unsigned char

Tags: c++, char, concatenation, unsigned

I have unsigned char array[8] and I want to make another unsigned char array, which has 4 elements, for example new_array[4]. Its elements have to be like that:
    new_array[0] - concatenation of array[0] and array [1];
    new_array[1] - concatenation of array[2] and array [3];
    new_array[2] - concatenation of array[4] and array [5];
    new_array[3] - concatenation of array[6] and array [7];

For example, if array[0]=0x01 and array[1]=0x25, then new_array[0]=0x0125.
Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: `char`s are typically 8 bits. How do you expect to fit `0x0125` in a single `char`?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A single `unsigned char` cannot represent "the concatenation of two unsigned chars". (Think of two consecutive maximal values.)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to convert an unsigned char array with 8 elements into an unsigned short array with 4 elements?

Assuming that `final_array` is an `unsigned short[4]` and `initial_array` is an `unsigned char[8]`:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    final_array[i] = (initial_array[i*2] << 8) + initial_array[i*2 + 1];
}
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
final_array[0] = (initial_array[0] << 8) + initial_array[1];
final_array[1] = (initial_array[2] << 8) + initial_array[3];
final_array[2] = (initial_array[4] << 8) + initial_array[5];
final_array[3] = (initial_array[6] << 8) + initial_array[7];
```

As a side note, on a Big Endian machine, you can `memcpy` the unsigned char buffer to the unsigned short buffer and it would work:

```
memcpy(final_array, initial_array, 8 * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

But I do **NOT** recommend it very much because

1. Involving endianness when you don't need to is a terrible idea if you want your sanity.
2. You'd be making assumptions about the size of a `short`. (Which, theoretically speaking, can vary as long as it holds at least 2 bytes and has a size that remains less than or equal to that of an `int`)